# Display All Products by Category with WooCommerce

Tags: categories, woocommerce-offtopic

With WooCommerce, I want to display all the categories in a store as headings, with all of their products listed below in an unordered list. Is this possible to do? I've seen a few things that'll let me display a list of categories or a list of products for a specific category, but nothing that'll loop through everything the way I described.

Here's what I'm currently using to list all categories:

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'number'     => $number,
    'orderby'    => $orderby,
    'order'      => $order,
    'hide_empty' => $hide_empty,
    'include'    => $ids
);
$product_categories = get_terms( 'product_cat', $args );
$count = count($product_categories);
if ( $count > 0 ){
    foreach ( $product_categories as $product_category ) {
        echo '<h4><a href="' . get_term_link( $product_category ) . '">' . $product_category->name . '</h4>';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: You simply need a loop of loops. Inside your `foreach()`, run a new `WP_Query()` to grab all the products in that term.. and then loop through those.

Comment: I think I understand how to do this, but I can't find anything about listing products by category with PHP (all I can find is shortcode nonsense). If you can show me what that code looks like, I should be able to figure out the rest.

Comment: You don't need a shortcode, listing products by category is just a [Tax Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters).

Comment: I knew I didn't need a shortcode, I was saying that's all I could find, which was unhelpful. That link you provided looks promising, I'll give it a shot tomorrow and report back, thanks.

Comment: Ok. If you are still stuck, edit your question with your new coding attempt and I'll take a look.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Figured it out! The code below automatically lists all categories and each categories posts!

```
$args = array(
    'number'     => $number,
    'orderby'    => 'title',
    'order'      => 'ASC',
    'hide_empty' => $hide_empty,
    'include'    => $ids
);
$product_categories = get_terms( 'product_cat', $args );
$count = count($product_categories);
if ( $count > 0 ){
    foreach ( $product_categories as $product_category ) {
        echo '<h4><a href="' . get_term_link( $product_category ) . '">' . $product_category->name . '</a></h4>';
        $args = array(
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'tax_query' => array(
                'relation' => 'AND',
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    // 'terms' => 'white-wines'
                    'terms' => $product_category->slug
                )
            ),
            'post_type' => 'product',
            'orderby' => 'title,'
        );
        $products = new WP_Query( $args );
        echo "<ul>";
        while ( $products->have_posts() ) {
            $products->the_post();
            ?>
                <li>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                        <?php the_title(); ?>
                    </a>
                </li>
            <?php
        }
        echo "</ul>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice. If you want to get really crazy you might want to look into the [Transients API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API)... that would help keep you from running so many queries on every page load.

Comment: How can I get the image thumbnails for each category?

Comment: @AlyssaReyes categories don't inherently have thumbnails; did you set up a custom field for your categories for this? Could you post this in a new question with more detail and send me the link so I can better understand?

Comment: Thanks man, you saved me some time and set me in the right direction. The only way I could improve this answer is to use WooCommerce's built-in query class: `WC_Product_Query`, instead of `WP_Query`, then use a `foreach` loop instead of a `while` loop. For reasons why, take a look at the Github documentation for the query: https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/wc_get_products-and-WC_Product_Query#description, but the gist is: > "custom WP_Queries queries is likely to break your code in future versions of WooCommerce as data moves towards custom tables for better performance."