# List posts with slug title

Tags: custom-taxonomy, slug

The code is for `single-product.php`. 
I can list all products on page but I want to list all posts with slug titles.

```
<?php
$args= array(
    'post_type'      => 'products',
    'order_by'       => 'date',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post__not_in'   => array( get_the_ID() ),
);

$wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );

while( $wp_query->have_posts() ) {
    $wp_query->the_post();
    echo '<a href="' . get_the_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a>';
}
```

**Example:**

1. Samsung ->(slug / category)

   - Galaxy note 5
   - Galaxy note 5
2. Apple ->(slug / category)

   - Iphone7
   - Iphone8

Comment: What is 'slug title'?

Comment: i have 3 slugs ( samsung, iphone, lg,....) more slugs will create later....

Answer (score 0):

If by "slug title" you mean a taxonomy (e.g. product category), then have a look at the code posted on the accepted answer on [Display All Products by Category with WooCommerce](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/139196/display-all-products-by-category-with-woocommerce) It should give you an idea (or even the complete solution) how to get your posts listed.